# I'm having a problem with stopping python mid process

Tags: python, input, breakpoints, pyautogui

```
import pydirectinput
import keyboard
import time
key = keyboard
auto = pydirectinput

keyPressed = False

while True:
   if key.is_pressed("f5"):
      keyPressed = True
      time.sleep(0.5)
   if key.is_pressed("f6"):
      keyPressed = False
      time.sleep(0.5)

   if keyPressed:
      auto.press("e")
      auto.press("q")
```

so far my code works and does exactly what I wish, but sometimes, due to the order of a loop being linear, it will not pick up me inputting f6 because it is in the middle of another process. Any advice on how to make the f6 check be constantly run and not be dependent on the "position of the process" If this question makes no sense just ask me to explain it better.

Comment: The `time.sleep` is most likely your problem, is there any reason for it?

Comment: That was just there so the code wouldn't take multiple inputs within a specific amount of time. Basically I had it where only the f6 key was used and it would just flip the keyPressed, without the sleep it could take hundreds of inputs just by me hitting f6, making it a random chance of what the value of keyPressed would be

Answer (score 0):

The way you can get around using `time.sleep` and avoid the code triggering multiple times while the key is held down is only toggle `keyPressed` when f6 is pressed and it wasn't pressed last iteration (keydown) or if it is not pressed and it was pressed last iteration (keyup). To trigger `keyPressed` whey f6 is released, your code would look like:

```py
keyPressedPreviously = False
if keyPressedPreviously and !key.is_pressed('f6'): # key was released     
    keyPressed = !keyPressed
if key.is_pressed('f6'):
     keyPressedPreviously = True
```